# How to print dictionary into two columns Google Sheets

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets

I am trying workarounds for a discord command that modifies a document.

I am have a simple question: is it possible to update a whole column with something like `sheet.update('B:B', scores)` with a dictionary (multiple objects)? I want to have columns B and C updated with the keys being in B and values in C.

Before I had to use code specified in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63334270/11805086), and make two lists (one with the names `[B]` and one with the values `[C]`) with the names and values in their own lists, so they were nested.

```py
for count in range(len(data['guild']['members'])): # For every guild member:
    res = requests.get("https://playerdb.co/api/player/minecraft/" + data['guild']['members'][count]['uuid']) # Response from server

    if res.status_code != 200: # If it wasn't a success, continue the loop and print a message
        ctx.author.send("Error 1: Invaild name from player database API!")
        continue

    name = res.json()['data']['player']['username'] # We know it was successful if we got to this point, so it's safe to try and get data from our response
    names.append(name)

# Members' GXP
    xp = data['guild']['members'][count]['expHistory']
    xp = sum(xp.values())
    xpHist.append(xp)

# Weekly Total
wTotal = sum(xpHist)
print(xpHist)
```

That didn't work in the command and I am trying a dictionary method with the enumerate function.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Updated to reference code as got striked for that :)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] showing your attempt and why it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the following with a simple `for` loop.

1. Add "Keys" to Cell A1 and "Values" to Cell B1.
2. Make a variable `idx` or anything and set it 2 as we already set A1 and B1 cell to "Keys" and "Values".
3. Iterate through `dict.items()` and update cell "A{idx}" to key and "B{idx}" to key and value respectively.
4. Add one to `idx` so while iterating to nth key and value, it does not update the same cell

```py
sheet.update_cell("A1", "Keys")
sheet.update_cell("B1", "Values")
idx = 2
for k, v in dict.items():
    sheet.update_cell(f"A{idx}", k)
    sheet.update_cell(f"B{idx}", v)
    idx += 1
```

Comment: Hi Poojan, while this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember, you're writing this answer for OP _and everybody else who sees it in the future._ Also, we don't encourage no-effort questions such as this one where OP shows no attempt to figure out an answer themselves, and answering such questions only encourages more. For these questions, it's appropriate to ask for their attempt and a [mre], and to vote to close for lack of detail.

Comment: thanks, I will keep this in mind for further answers and have updated this answer too